# Whats the best visual page designer for .NET web applications?

Tags: visual-studio, user-interface

Im currently working on the GUI for an ASP.NET MVC application using Visual Studio 2005. The visual webpage designer (for the views) is awful.

Any input on what other people use would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having installed and tested several products over the past few days, I have come to the conclusion that **Microsoft Expression Studio** is probably the best option when it comes to a visual design aid. Its code is clean and compliant, and although fairly basic, it allows you to create your layouts as required.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to advice you to create your markup by hand as everybody else does. Using designers is mostly unprofessional and leads to low quality results.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2008 was a big step forward over 2005. 2005 was horrible. And Visual Studio 2010 is better yet - the quick snippets can save you a bunch of time once you get used to them.